# Discord.py Class Definition not getting a variable when it's clearly inputted

Tags: python, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os
import random
import re

prefix = 'bz '
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)




@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as: ')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('---------------')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='bz help'))


class DataCreate(commands.Cog):
    def __int__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    async def createdatacash(self, member):
        path = 'bal_' + member + '.txt'
        print('createddatacash')
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            file = open(path, 'w+')
            file.write('0')
            file.close()
            self.data = True
    async def writefile(self, member, inputthing):
        path = 'bal_' + member + '.txt'
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            await DataCreate.createdatacash(member)
        file = open(path, 'w+')
        file.write(str(inputthing))
        self.data = True





class GetCash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    async def view_cash(self, member):
        path = 'bal_' + member + '.txt'
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            datacreate = DataCreate
            await datacreate.createdatacash(member)
        file = open(path, 'r')
        output= file.read()
        file.close()
        self.data = output


class CashModify(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    async def addtobal(self, member, amount):
        path = 'bal_' + member + '.txt'
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            datacreate = DataCreate
            await datacreate.createdatacash(member)
        getcash = GetCash
        bal_amount = getcash.view_cash(member)
        output = int(bal_amount) + int(amount)
        datacreate = DataCreate
        await datacreate.writefile(member, output)





@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def daily(ctx):
    numlist = []
    x=99
    person = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    for x in range(99,600):
        x+=1
        numlist.append(x)
    secure_random = random.SystemRandom()
    cash = secure_random.choice(numlist)
    print(str(cash))
    cashmodify = CashModify
    print('ran')
    await cashmodify.addtobal(person, cash)
    getcash = GetCash
    channel = client.get_channel(ctx.message.channel.id)
    channel.send("You gained " + str(cash) + ' credits, spend wisely!")
```

My source code is above, I hope this will suffice

There Error I get `missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'`

This Error is showed at: `await cashmodify.addtobal(person, cash)`

I've been experimenting with making an economy bot with discord rewrite for python 3.7 and I decided this time to make it easier on myself is to keep them in classes and then use them whenever I need them, but whenever I run the command in discord, it says that I am missing an required positional argument called amount. I've tried switching the input from strings and integers and I've looked back at the class and it still won't work.

Another thing I've tried is removing commands.Cog, but that still doesn't work.
So I'd appreciate any help anyone can give me

Comment: Why are you creating these cogs at all?  Every cog should be an independent unit, they shouldn't rely on each other. Get rid of the cogs and just have these be normal functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of a class and call one of its methods, `self` (which represents the instance of your class) will be passed to it as an argument.

This code does not create an instance of your class, it just creates a class object:

```
>>> cashmodify = CashModify
>>> cashmodify
<class '__main__.CashModify'>
```

The `addtobal` method is defined like this `addtobal(self, member, amount)`, and you're calling it like this `addtobal(person, cash)`.

You get an error because you are not creating any instance of the class `CashModify`: there is no `self` attribute, so your `person` and `cash` variable are passed as the `self` and `member` arguments respectively, and nothing is passed to `amount`.

To resolve this problem, you have to instantiate your class (create an instance of it) accordingly to your `__init__` method and pass to it a client variable:

```
cashmodify = CashModify(client)
```